# Material-UI v1: How to set one font size for all the components in material-ui v1?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are using 1.4.5 material-ui in our application. Now we are trying to set one font size for all of the components in our application. For example we want to set `fontSize: 14px,` for headers / buttons / paragraph /list... and so on. 
Here is our sample theme configuration:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  palette: {
    primary: purple,
    secondary: green,
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
});
```

If you notice we have tried to define the font size in a `typography` object but  with this configuration, material-ui computes a font size according to the formula given at [this link.](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#typography-font-size)

We are trying to achieve a 14px font-size application wide but we can not find an option to do this. One option can be a `pxToRem` function but I am not sure how should I overwrite that function and what should be my function?  The other option is to define styles in every component and I think that is a bit overkill since we should able to do it with theme object. 
Please help me if you can think of a way to set the font size globally. 
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NOTE: I am not sure why somebody will downvote my answer since my
>   answer is based in material-ui docs. Here is [the link](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/). Please
>   expand typography section and you will see this is how all the fonts
>   are set. Please comment here the reason for the downvote. Also, note
>   when I wrote this answer I was using Material UI 1.4.5

I will post the solution that solved my problem. Hopefully, this will help someone else as well:
I end up defining the font size in a [typography](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/) property of my theme. Here is how I set it up in the theme;

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    fontSize: 13,
    display4: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    display3: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    display2: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    display1: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    headline: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    subheading: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    body2: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    body1: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    caption: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    button: {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
  },
  palette: {
    primary: purple,
    secondary: green,
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
});
```

I have noticed if you used `Div` instead of `PAPER` element sometimes formatting does not apply (bug with material-ui??). So I end up creating a global class which I applied to any elements which were overriding my theme styles.

```
  overRidefonts: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  },
```

Comment: Great tips, will implement this for the time being.